# Populate an array with matrix elements from a file in Scala

Tags: scala

How do I populate an array with matrix elements from a file in Scala?
I know that

```
    for (val line<- Source.fromFile("mask.txt").getLines){
    }
```

will fetch the elements row by row but how do I split each row into individual elements and store them as elements of an array?

Answer (score 1):

You could just call `split` on `line` and you'll get back an array of elements to do whatever it is you wish with each element.

```
for (val line<- Source.fromFile("mask.txt").getLines){
    line.split(<your delimiter>);    
}
```

The result of the split will be an  `Array[java.lang.String]`

Answer (score 0):

If mask.txt looks like this:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Then you can do this:

```
Source.fromFile("mask.txt").getLines.map(_.split(",")).toArray
```

to get an Array of Arrays that is basically:

```
Array(Array(1, 2, 3),
      Array(4, 5, 6),
      Array(7, 8, 9))
```

Comment: I get "error: value toArray is not a member of Iterator[Array[java.lang.String]]" on trying this.

Comment: @user3039976, are you using an old version of scala?

Comment: @user3039976, WOW! That's super-crazy out of date.  It was released over 4 years ago!  You should update to 2.10.3 immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
    var y = new ArrayBuffer[String]()
    for(val line<- Source.fromFile("mask.txt").getLines){
        for( val ele <- line.split(" ")){
            y +=ele
        }
    }
```